# Facebook Analytics User Activities count wrong

Tags: ios, facebook-analytics

We use Facebook Analytics to count daily active user. howerver the number of iOS shows very different with the number counted by server. The data count by Facebook is much smaller than ourselves. We count active user by api access log. I wonder how Facebook Analytics count the data?

Answer (score 1):

Hope below links will answer your question:
https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/1443115332373848
https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/1747887018756757

Eli from Facebook Analytics